# can't start pipewire-pulse in ubuntu 23.10

Tags: 23.10, pipewire

i have meet a problem that via

```
systemctl --user start  pipewire-pulse
```

can not start pipewire-pulse.service, but pipewire and wireplumber is ok

log attached following:

https://dpaste.com/7JPM3KCL4

Comment: Log analysis shows that the socket node is occupied, but I don’t know why.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to replace a unix socket to ensure pipewire-pulse communicates with pactl

Comment: Could you please elaborate?